# "past harm" from The Hunger Games

Tags: phrase-meaning

Origin:

> I can’t bring myself to leave her like this. Past harm, but seeming utterly defenseless.

My Question:

I searched online but still wasn't able to get this straight.

Does "past harm" mean "harmless" or "she went through harms done to her"?

Context:

> I can’t stop looking at Rue, smaller than ever, a baby animal curled up in a nest of netting. I can’t bring myself to leave her like this. Past harm, but seeming utterly defenseless. To hate the boy from District 1, who also appears so vulnerable in death, seems inadequate. It’s the Capitol I hate, for doing this to all of us (from Chapter 18 of *The Hunger Games*)

There are very few sentence examples online with this phrase, so please help.

Answer (score 6):

"Past harm" means that no further harm can be done to the person. Most often it means "already dead" so there is no way to do further harm.

I read *The Hunger Games* several years ago, but I don't recall the context of that passage.

Based on the newly added contest, it would seem that the narrator does indeed think that Rue is dead at this point. The phrase "...who also appears so vulnerable in death, ..." seems to confirm this.

Comment: Chapter 18: I can’t stop looking at Rue, smaller than ever, a baby animal curled up in a nest of netting. I can’t bring myself to leave her like this. Past harm, but seeming utterly defenseless. To hate the boy from District 1, who also appears so vulnerable in death, seems inadequate. It’s the Capitol I hate, for doing this to all of us.